# when trying to rotate a camera across the X axis it zooms out

Tags: 3d, processing

So I'm trying to learn how to add 3D in my Processing programs. While learning I saw the camera function, and started to play around with it. The way it works is that if the d key is pressed, the camera shifts, and if the a key is pressed it shifts to the other direction. W zooms out, and S zooms in. My problem is, while rotating it across the X Axis it starts to zoom out.

```
float z = (height/2) / tan(PI/5);
float x = width/2;
char lastpressed;
void setup() {
  size(640, 360, P3D);
}
void draw() {
  camera(x, height/2, z, width/2, height/2, 0, 0, 1, 0);
  background(0);
  if (keyPressed && key == 'd') {
    x += 5;
    lastpressed = 'd';
  }
  if (keyPressed && key == 'a') {
    lastpressed = 'a';
    x -= 5;
  }
  if (keyPressed && key == 's') {
    z += 5;
    lastpressed = 's';
  }
  if (keyPressed && key == 'w' && z >= 40) {
    z -= 5;
    lastpressed = 'w';
  }
  translate(width/2, height/2, -100);
  lights();
  box(200);
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything related to a rotation in the code.

Answer (score 0):

While it gives the impression is rotating and zooming, the camera is only moving alongside the X axis describing what they call a [lateral tracking shot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SRnFkyvIGr0). I tried my hand at it while changing the least amount of code and I came up with this:

```
float radius = 300;
float angle = 0;
char lastpressed;
void setup() {
  size(640, 360, P3D);
}
void draw() {
  translate(width/2, height/2, 0);
  float ypos= 0;
  float xpos= cos(radians(angle))*radius;
  float zpos= sin(radians(angle))*radius;

  camera(xpos, ypos, zpos, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0);

  background(0);
  if (keyPressed && key == 'd') {
    lastpressed = 'd';
    angle+=5;
  }
  if (keyPressed && key == 'a') {
    lastpressed = 'a';
    angle-=5;
  }
  if (keyPressed && key == 's') {
    lastpressed = 's';
    radius += 20;
  }
  if (keyPressed && key == 'w' && radius > 200) {
    lastpressed = 'w';
    radius -= 20;
  }

  lights();
  box(200);
}
```